# php Regex on email addresses

Tags: php, regex

trying to filter out some specific email addresses.  I run a query which returns data like so

```
smtp:email@email.local
X400:C=GB;A= ;P=TRACK;O=Exchange;
SMTP:email@email.com

smtp:Email.4c1f4d8b-8179-4148-93bf-00a95fa1e042@email.com
X400:c=GB;a= ;p=TRACK;o=Exchange;s=Email.4c1f4d8b-8179-4148-93bf-0;
smtp:Email.4c1f4d8b-8179-4148-93bf-00a95fa1e042@email.co.uk
smtp:Email.4c1f4d8b-8179-4148-93bf-00a95fa1e042@email.local

X400:c=GB;a= ;p=TRACK;o=Exchange;s=Mailbox D919BA05-46A6-415;
SMTP:Mailbox{D919BA05-46A6-415f-80AD-7E09334BB852}@email.com
smtp:Mailbox{D919BA05-46A6-415f-80AD-7E09334BB852}@email.co.uk
smtp:Mailbox{D919BA05-46A6-415f-80AD-7E09334BB852}@email.local
```

What I need to return is "normal" email addresses.  So from the above, I need to return

```
smtp:email@email.local
SMTP:email@email.com
```

First of all, I need to get rid of anything that does not start with smtp/SMTP.  The abnormal email address have 3 or hyphens before the @ symbol.  I was thinking I could use this to get rid of the bad email addresses.

I have attempted something that kind of works, but I do not think it is the best.  What I have is

```
/smtp:\w+(-\w+)?@.*/im
```

Whats the best way to get the good email addresses out of my list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this works any better with your real cases:

```
$pattern = '/smtp:([\w]*?@.*?\.(com|local))$/im';

preg_match_all($pattern, $emails, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch all RFC 822 compatible email addresses, consider using this regex :

```
/smtp:([^][()<>@,;:\\\\\". \\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]+|\"(\\n|(\\\\\\r)*([^\"\\\\\\r\\n]|\\\\[^\\r]))*(\\\\\\r)*\")(\\.([^][()<>@,;:\\\\\". \\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]+|\"(\\n|(\\\\\\r)*([^\"\\\\\\r\\n]|\\\\[^\\r]))*(\\\\\\r)*\"))*@([^][()<>@,;:\\\\\". \\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]+|\\[(\\n|(\\\\\\r)*([^][\\\\\\r\\n]|\\\\[^\\r]))*(\\\\\\r)*])(\\.([^][()<>@,;:\\\\\". \\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]+|\\[(\\n|(\\\\\\r)*([^][\\\\\\r\\n]|\\\\[^\\r]))*(\\\\\\r)*]))*/im
```

That means your code would look something like this :

```
$pattern = "/smtp:([^][()<>@,;:\\\\\". \\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]+|\"(\\n|(\\\\\\r)*([^\"\\\\\\r\\n]|\\\\[^\\r]))*(\\\\\\r)*\")(\\.([^][()<>@,;:\\\\\". \\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]+|\"(\\n|(\\\\\\r)*([^\"\\\\\\r\\n]|\\\\[^\\r]))*(\\\\\\r)*\"))*@([^][()<>@,;:\\\\\". \\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]+|\\[(\\n|(\\\\\\r)*([^][\\\\\\r\\n]|\\\\[^\\r]))*(\\\\\\r)*])(\\.([^][()<>@,;:\\\\\". \\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]+|\\[(\\n|(\\\\\\r)*([^][\\\\\\r\\n]|\\\\[^\\r]))*(\\\\\\r)*]))*/im";

preg_match_all($pattern, $emails, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Thats useful, but unfortunately the ones I do not want are RFC 822 complient

Comment: @kate_hudson : what criteria need to be followed then?